# ViewData inside of ViewData string

Tags: c#, mono

I am loading a table dynamically, and there is an unknown number of rows. Each row (each cell, actually) is loaded from the database and concatenated into a string:

```
tableItems+="<td colspan='8' class='reportHeaderMain borderThin'> @ViewData[\"" + tString + "Title\"]</td>";
```

in the code above, tString is the item number, so the title would be something like "12345Title". Later in the controller ActionResult, I assign a value to the ViewData item:

```
ViewData[tString + "Title"] = ((linkedArrayList)tObj[temp]).getInfo("Brand");
```

During breakpoints, all values store correctly, but it renders on the page as "@ViewData["..."]" instead of the ViewData value. I imagine this is because the preprocessor is doing a once-over but not a twice-over; this is to write, it is rendering the string value correctly, but not processing the resultant string (note: the markup displays correctly). This could be inherent to Mono, or it could be because, in the view, I am using HTML Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewData["tableItems"])
```

I realize it is not the best practice to generate markup in the controller like this, but this is what I am working with. Does anybody have any ideas on how to get the ViewData in the string to render as the value (e.g., brand name) rather than "ViewData[...]"? Alternative approaches are more than welcome, though (since I am new to MVC) I politely ask for details if another approach is the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid...I would delete this question, but it might actually help fellow newbs to MVC. If anybody has a similar issue, remember where you are trying to add the value. The only place a situation like this would occur is in the controller, where you have full access to the values assigned to the ViewData. For example, if you are assigning the value of tObj to the ViewBag, then trying to load the ViewData, just concatenate with tObj. Sorry for wasting your time, guys, I learned something.